# How to use apply family functions for two dataframe with different rows instead of nested loop

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe  and another comparatively smaller dataframe of different row count that I need to match any term. I want to use an apply family functions to avoid nested for loop. Here is what I am trying to achieve but without the loop to make it efficient

A sample code is below. I have two dataframes with different rows, say, animal and rand_string. I need to update the values of 'new' column in rand_string based on animal column in the animal dataframe.

```
animal <- c("llama", "meerkat", "coyote") %>% as.data.frame() %>% rename(animal = ".") %>%
  mutate(type = "mamal") %>%
  rbind(data.frame(animal = "hawk", type = "bird")) %>%
  rbind(data.frame(animal = "bee", type = "insect"))

rand_string <- ids::adjective_animal(1E6, n_adjectives=1) %>% as.data.frame() %>% rename(animal = ".")
rand_string2 <- rand_string[1:50,] %>% as.data.frame() %>% rename(animal = ".") %>% mutate(new = NA)
for(i in 1:nrow(rand_string2)){
  #print(paste0("rand_string2$animal[i]:",rand_string2$animal[i]))
  for(j in 1:nrow(animal)){
    if(grepl(animal$animal[j],rand_string2$animal[i])){
      #print(animal$animal[j])
      rand_string2$new[i] = animal$type[j]
    }
  }
}
View(rand_string2)
```

I tried few apply functions but getting error since they have different row counts. Any help would be much appreciated!

Update: I updated the code example for the animal dataframe to reflect the original dataframe

Updated Data:

```
animal <- data.frame(animal = c("llama|deer|hound|meerkat|coyote", "hawk|parrot|finch", "bee|junebug|butterfly"),
                     type = c("mamal", "bird", "insect"))
```

Update again: fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join() worked for my patternless column in my actual dataframe. It takes a bit time but not as much as the loop. Thanks @benson23

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a `for loop` or `apply` in this case, a `left_join()` is already enough.

You can either use `fuzzy join::regex_left_join()` or `dplyr::left_join()`. But since there're 1 million rows in your `rand_string` dataframe, `regex_left_join()` might be too inefficient. Therefore I recommend using `dplyr::left_join()`.

First remove the "adjectives" in your `rand_string`, so that pure animal name can be used to join with the `animal` dataset. Then split the multiple records in the `animal` data frame into single record per rows. After that, `left_join` the two sets and remove the newly created `animal2` column, and `rename` from `type` to `new`.

#### Code

```
library(dplyr)

rand_string$animal2 <- gsub("^[a-z].+?(?<=_)", "", rand_string$animal, perl = T)

left_join(rand_string, 
          separate_rows(animal, animal, sep = "\\|"), 
          by = c("animal2" = "animal")) |> 
  select(-animal2) |> 
  rename("new" = "type")
```

#### Data

```
set.seed(52)
animal <- data.frame(animal = c("llama|deer|hound|meerkat|coyote", "hawk|parrot|finch", "bee|junebug|butterfly"),
                     type = c("mamal", "bird", "insect"))

rand_string <- ids::adjective_animal(1E6, n_adjectives=1) %>% as.data.frame() %>% rename(animal = ".")
```

Comment: I tried left join earlier. This is a sample dataframe I put together for the question. The issue is the 2nd dataframe that I am working with has multiple terms(animal column in the animal dataframe). So I need to grepl to match the terms. If there is a syntax for that while doing the left join that that might work.

Comment: @Dutta can you update your question to include some dummy columns that can mimic your actual dataset? Let's see if there's any workaround using `left_join`

Comment: Thank you @benson23 for your help. I updated the code example for animal dataframe.

Comment: @Dutta See if my updated answer helps :)

Comment: I like the separate_rows() function that you suggested. This solution would have been perfect if I had a pattern in my actual rand_string dataframe to create another column similar to animal2 to join by.

Comment: fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join worked!! Thanks so much! @benson23